# What is the appropriate age for a kid to read and/or understand the books related to self confidence?

Tags: education, age-appropriate

At what age ***does it help*** and is possible ***to be able to read and understand*** the books like
[The power of your subconcious mind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1434440826) and [The magic of thinking big](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671646788)?

How should these kind of books be introduced such that the child starts believing and implementing what's written there?

Comment: long before they can read them, you can tell them the material in the books (and live it) and they can get the benefit that way

Comment: Given that your other two questions refer to your child being 1.5 months old, I'd say the answer is "older than that".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as children can understand what you are telling them, you can tell them what the books would.  An earlier question on here about kisses on booboos had this answer:

> When my daughter was a preschooler her body reacted a lot to things others don't notice. One bug bite would swell her hand so she could barely use it. She was allergic to Solarcaine. I would tell her "tell your hand to stop swelling now" and she, not knowing that was a ridiculous request, would comply - **and the swelling would go down**.

([Why do kisses stop a child from hurting?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7540/why-do-kisses-stop-a-child-from-hurting/7542#7542))

So this approach worked at that age for the girl, even though she probably couldn't read and understand books like that. Start talking to your child about the power of your mind right away, and when they are old enough to read, it will be easier to understand those books, as they will have already been living those words.